# Finding subdirectories inside all directories with the same name

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I want to run a command to:

1. Find all directories named "`inc`" under a folder "`X`".
2. List all the subdirectories under each "`X/.../inc/`".
3. Redirect the output to a file named "`list`"

I tried various combinations of the below command, without success:

```
$ find X/ -name "inc" -print | xargs find {} -type d > list
find: path must precede expression
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`find` can do this all by itself:

```
find X -path '*/inc/*' -type d > list
```

Read the `-path` part of `man find` for more info.

As I mentioned quickly in a comment: if you store the directories line separated in a text file, directory names containing newlines won't be unambiguously representable. If you are *certain* that directories don't contain newlines, that's OK. Just a general remark.

Comment: yea. i gave the same answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10647823/571189)

Comment: Or find X -name 'inc' -type d > list

Comment: @MaQleod: No, that is not the question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a handy one-liner:

```
find X -type d -name "inc" -exec sh -c 'find {} -type d' \; > list
```

It runs `find` on each of the first `find` results. The `exec` option can also take a minimal shell command, in which – as I said – `{}` is replaced with each directory of the first `find`.

The second `find` will, per your request, "list all subdirectories" of the first results, including the `inc` directory. If you don't want that itself in the output, let the second `find` *at least* output folders of depth 1.

```
find X -type d -name "inc" -exec sh -c 'find {} -mindepth 1 -type d' \; > list
```

We'll then just redirect the command's `stdout` into `list`.

Comment: a variation on that answer was helpful to me where I only wanted depth 1 sub directories of the original match
    `find path -name inc -type d -exec sh -c 'find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d' \;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   find path-of-x -path '*/inc/*' -type d > list
```

Comment: i don't have linux machine to test it now...

Comment: This doesn't work. But thanks for suggesting me `"\inc\"` :)

Comment: @iammilind: try with `-path` flag

Answer (score 1):

Alright I have found the answer to simulate this nested find:

```
find X/ -type d | grep "/inc/" > list
```

Comment: Nice, that'll work, too! However, in Unix/Linux shells, there's really no such thing as ***the*** answer. It's a mixture of personal preferences and what's easy to follow.

Comment: To take care of unconventional (but existing) file names with e.g. newlines: `find X/ -type d -print0 | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"}/\/inc\//' > list` (`grep -z` also delimits on the null character, but its output seems to be null separated as well, so then one would need to pipe it through e.g. `xargs -0L1 echo` to get it line by line). In this case, since you are saving the list to file with every entry separated by newline, newlines in file names will _still_ be ambiguously represented. Perhaps you do not even need the intermediate file, depending on what you want to do with the list.