# Finding last depth directories inside all directories with the same name

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I already saw the question: [Finding subdirectories inside all directories with the same name](https://superuser.com/questions/425935/finding-subdirectories-inside-all-directories-with-the-same-name)

Now my directory structure is:

```
$ find .

.
./4
./4/1
./2
./2/1
./5
./5/1
./1
./1/1
./3
./3/1
```

I want to list all the directories at the end with "1" in their name:

```
./4/1
./2/1
./5/1
./1/1
./3/1
```

but I don't want

```
./1
```

I have tried the following commands:

```
find . -name "*1*"
find . -type d -path '*/1*'
find . -path '*/1*' -depth 2 -type d
find . -depth 2 -path '*/1*' -type d
```

**UPDATE**

```
find . -depth 2
```

gives the error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: 2
```

**Found my solution**

```
find -mindepth 2 . -type d -path "*1*"
```

Can anybody explain why -depth didn't work while -mindepth worked ?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

```
find -mindepth 2 . -type d -path "*1*"
```

**Explaination [found here](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Directories.html)**

> — Option: `-maxdepth levels`
>
> Descend at most `levels` (a non-negative integer) levels of directories
> below the command line arguments. `-maxdepth 0` means only apply the
> tests and actions to the command line arguments.
>
> — Option: `-mindepth levels`
>
> Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than `levels` (a
> non-negative integer). `-mindepth 1` means process all files except
> the command line arguments.
>
> — Option: `-depth`
>
> Process each directory's contents before the directory itself. Doing
> this is a good idea when producing lists of files to archive with `cpio`
> or `tar`. If a directory does not have write permission for its owner,
> its contents can still be restored from the archive since the
> directory's permissions are restored after its contents.

I got confused between these options.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution for common filesystems (ext* and xfs at least), if you don't know the depth of your subdirs :

```
find -type d -links 2
```

On other filesystems, a solution could be :

```
find -type d | sort -r | awk 'a!~"^"$0{a=$0;print}' | sort
```

Comment: **For it to be a good solution you need to know the filesystem(s) involved.** In many filesystems a directory without subdirectories reports 2 links, a directory with subdirectories reports more than 2 links. In some filesystems it's different and then your answer will not work. E.g. in Btrfs the link count of a directory it's always(?) 1.

Comment: You are right I've edited my answer to more be filesystem independant, but I think the "links" version might be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody explain why `-depth` didn't work while `-mindepth` worked?

I can. `-depth` didn't work while `-mindepth` worked because you're using the "wrong" implementation of `find`.

You are right in [your answer](https://superuser.com/a/1290298/432690) `-depth` has nothing to do with the problem and cannot solve it *for you*. You are apparently using (and linking to the documentation of) GNU `find`; it supports `-depth`, `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` exactly as your answer states.

[`find` in FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) supports `-depth n`:

> True if the depth of the file relative to the starting point of the traversal is `n`.

**Your `-depth 2` *would* work With FreeBSD implementation of `find`.**

Note FreeBSD `find` *also* supports `-depth` (without any option-argument) and its meaning is identical to `-depth` in GNU `find`. This usage of `-depth` is mandated by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). `-depth n` or `-mindepth n` and `-maxdepth n` are non-portable extensions in respective implementations of `find`.